# NSFetchedResultsController returning nothing

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When I do a fetch against a table in core data that has data in it, it doesn't appear to come back with any results.

I have performed a read on the table prior to doing the fetch and the data is there.

Here is the code.

```
func fetchAllFoods() ->  NSFetchedResultsController {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    //3 - set the correct table
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(self.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "foodCategory", ascending: true)

    let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor] //, secondSortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    //4 - navigate in relationship to group by startdate
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "foodCategory",
        cacheName: nil)

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self


    return aFetchedResultsController

}
```

When I put a break just before the return, this is what shows.

[image]

No sections, no data.

I am sure I am missing something fundamental here so let me know if I need to share more information.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [`performFetch:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/performFetch:) on the fetched results controller:

```
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(...)
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
var error : NSError?
if !aFetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error) {
    // report error ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something basic and I can't believe I missed that.

As a side note, "let error..." will throw an error at the "&error".  Seems that using var instead of let clears it up.

Thanks again.